# Communication between Kubernetes Pods

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-service, kubernetes-statefulset

I have statefulset pods. When I go inside one of the pods and try to ping the hostname of it. It works. But if I try to ping the hostnames of other pods from current containers, then those hostnames do not get resolved. I have headless service also in place. Could someone please tell me bare minimum what needs to be done at cluster level or in yaml of either service or statefulset to make the communication happen. An working example or some working charts link to try out, would be helpful. I can go through that.

Service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: "{{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.AppVersion | replace "." "" }}"
  labels:
    app: "{{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.AppVersion | replace "." "" }}"
{{ include "metadata.labels.standard" . | indent 4 }}    
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
   tier: backend
```

StatefulSet:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: "{{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.AppVersion | replace "." "" }}-myapp1"
  labels:
    app: "{{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.AppVersion | replace "." "" }}-myapp1"
    tier: backend
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: "{{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.AppVersion | replace "." "" }}-myapp1"
  serviceName: "{{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.AppVersion | replace "." "" }}"
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: "{{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.AppVersion | replace "." "" }}-myapp1"
        tier: backend
      volumes:
        - name: configmap-r
          configMap:
           name: "{{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.AppVersion | replace "." "" }}-configmap"
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: {{ .Values.image.pullSecret }}
      containers:
        - name: "{{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.AppVersion | replace "." "" }}-myapp1"
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          volumeMounts:
            - name: configmap-r
              mountPath: /home/xyz/
```

Pods:

```
pod/calico-kube-controllers-59fc8847c-vv9bt   1/1     Running            0          3h27m
pod/calico-node-4gktj                         1/1     Running            0          3h27m
pod/coredns-5c98db65d4-tctgk                  1/1     Running            13         63d
pod/coredns-5c98db65d4-v8gtv                  1/1     Running            13         63d
pod/etcd-minikube                             1/1     Running            2          63d
pod/kube-addon-manager-minikube               1/1     Running            2          63d
pod/kube-apiserver-minikube                   1/1     Running            0          15d
pod/kube-controller-manager-minikube          1/1     Running            6          63d
pod/kube-proxy-qc9nx                          1/1     Running            1          63d
pod/kube-scheduler-minikube                   1/1     Running            6          63d
pod/storage-provisioner                       1/1     Running            3          63d
pod/tiller-deploy-6b9c575bfc-z7dgs            1/1     Running            1          62d


NAME                           TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE
service/kube-dns               ClusterIP   xx.xx.xx.xx     <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   63d
service/tiller-deploy          ClusterIP   xx.xx.xx.xx     <none>        44134/TCP                62d

NAME                         DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR                 AGE
daemonset.apps/calico-node   1         1         1       1            1           beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux   3h27m
daemonset.apps/kube-proxy    1         1         1       1            1           beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux   63d

NAME                                      READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/calico-kube-controllers   1/1     1            1           3h27m
deployment.apps/coredns                   2/2     2            2           63d
deployment.apps/tiller-deploy             1/1     1            1           62d

NAME                                                DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/calico-kube-controllers-59fc8847c   1         1         1       3h27m
replicaset.apps/coredns-5c98db65d4                  2         2         2       63d
replicaset.apps/tiller-deploy-6b9c575bfc            1         1         1       62d
```

`

Comment: add your service definition

Comment: @EfratLevitan added

Comment: Could you add your statefulset YAML, and how you are querying the other pods (whole command used)?

Comment: @Ezwig added the yaml. Like this I have another same yaml for myapp2. I am going inside myapp1 and trying to fire this command
$ping <hostname of myapp2 pod>

Comment: @Nish The whole command you are using to querie the other pods could have useful information too

Comment: @Ezwig I have modified the comment. Include the command as well

Comment: Could you try pinging your pod using this domain name? 
ping (hostname).(headlessservicename).default.svc.cluster.local

Comment: I tried that also..It's not working

Comment: @Nish could you add to your question the output of `kubectl get all -n kube-system`

Comment: @Ezwig output added

Answer (score 0):

To expose service within cluster use the type value as clusterIP. Instead of using 
spec:
  clusterIP: None

Use this: 
Type: ClusterIP

Comment: Nish, can you please check and create service like Dashrath suggested and let us know if this worked?